# What does FXML stand for?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

The fxml from JavaFX? Could you please open the abbreviation?

All the acronym websites I found return nothing, the closest is from [dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-do-all-the-words-in-a-javafx-app-mean.html) But it isn't for sure.

Comment: Try clicking on the **[fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fxml/info)** tag in your question.

Comment: @l'L'l That only explains what it *is* and *does*, not what the acronym is *short for* (not that it's interesting).

Comment: @Kayaman: I assume it's the `FX` is taken from `JavaFX` and then chopped, and dropped onto `XML`... [Here's the intro PDF](http://fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Introducing-FXML.pdf) which still never points that out, so I could be fxtively wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FX Markup Language. In the same way that `HTML` is for Hypertext Markup Language, and many more acronyms that end in `ML`.

Comment: It's the `F` from `FX` which is a bastardization of `effects`. It has no real meaning.